# RoR: select_tag How to pass a list of selections to controller method on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, html-select

I have a multi select list:

```
<%= select_tag "selectedSuites", options_for_select(@suitesInSystem), {:multiple => true, :class => "chzn-select", :style => "width:100%;", :style => "height:100%"} %>
```

I now want to add a button to the same view, which will pass the list of selected options in my listbox back to a controller function, for some server side processing:

```
<button id='SyncButton' onclick="<%=controller.dostuff(selectedSuites_tag_selections)%>">Sync</button>
```

Can someone advise what I've failed to spot so far?!?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, can whoever marked this question down kindly explain why? If I've done something wrong, surely it's only fair to enlighten me as to what?!

Comment: You never call controller action directly from the view. Please read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html